# Facebook SDK - remove user permissions

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, permissions

My Android app has a Login Button that asks the user for a few permissions: public_profile, email, user_likes...

When I run the app for the first time and click the Login Button, it asks me to approve the permissions. Once I approve them, it shows the Logout Button.

However, now each time I Login it goes straight to Logout --it skips the permissions dialogue since I approved them already. I want the permissions dialogue to appear every time I click the Login Button -- for testing purposes.

How do I remove my user permissions after I have already approved them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm super late to the party, but currently, you can do this:

`new GraphRequest(currentAccessToken, "/me/permissions", null, HttpMethod.DELETE).executeAsync();`

Answer (score -1):

You can remove them from the facebook website https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications, click on your app, and edit the settings to remove permissions.